# Using a Factory in md.dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a google material dialog box where I interact with the user. I want to inject a factory into the dialog and use it there. Is there a way to do this?

I tried passing the factory as a local variable.

Any suggestions?

Edit ---------

Here is my controller that I am using to handle the dialogs. I output the factory to the console and the functions are all there. Not sure why calling them does nothing.

```
function DocumentDialogController($mdDialog, locals, chartFactory)
{
    var vm              = vm || this;
    vm.thisItem         = locals.thisItem;

    vm.cancel           = cancel;
    vm.acceptChanges    = acceptChanges;
    vm.selectImage      = selectImage;

    function cancel(){
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    function acceptChanges(desc) {
        $mdDialog.hide(desc);
    };

    function selectImage(imageName) {
        vm.thisItem.imageObj.data.src=imageName;
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a controller to the dialog and inject the factory into the controller.

Do something like the below to create the dialog. Note that the string in the controller property is the name of the controller you want to use.

```
$mdDialog.show({
    templateUrl: 'partials/example.template.html',
    targetEvent: event,
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
});
```

﻿Create and inject the factory into the controller like you would with any other controller.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('example')
    .controller('ExampleCtrl', ExampleCtrl);

  function ExampleCtrl(ExampleFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    // you can now use the injected ExampleFactory 
  }
  ExampleCtrl.$inject = ['ExampleFactory'];
})();
```

Comment: I updated the answer. It appears that the original injection was indeed working but the factory is a repeated embedding of some kind